# Этимология слова "почитать"

Tags: этимология

Дорогие, подскажите от какого слова происходит слово "почитать". И этимологию этого слова.
Спасибо большое

Comment: Прежде поясните значение слова, которое Вас интересует.

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю, что речь идет о слове "почитать" в значении "отдавать дань уважения". Но тут все просто - от слова "почет", который в свою очередь происходит от слова "чтить", образованное под влиянием слова "честь".

Comment: А "чтить" и "читать" - родственные слова? уж очень похожи!

Comment: Похоже, *что* морф Ч&Т не только в чтении, счете, чете, нечете и почтении присутствует, но и в самом нашем распространенном служебном слове ЧТО, которое обозначает-вопрошает любой объект или понятие))) Почтение : "Что изволите, батюшка? Что прикажете, матушка?" Воинская "честь" могла быть раньше частью общей добычи. "По заслугам и честь (твоя часть добытого)!" /// " А мои ти Куряни свѣдоми къмети ...
сами скачють, акы сѣрыи влъци въ
полѣ, **ищучи себе чти** , а князю
славѣ."